# How is the order for which keys are stored and reteived determined in awk?

Tags: awk, array

I am just starting to learn awk and was familiarizing myself with  associative arrays only to discover that the order in which the keys were retrieved (or stored) didn't make a whole lot of sense. As a result, I did some light research, but I kept on getting answers similar to "elements in an associative array are not stored in any particular order" ([Source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/An_Awk_Primer/Arrays#Sparseness_and_Lack_of_Order)) or best I found so far "The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk and in standard awk cannot be controlled or changed" ([Source](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html#Scanning-an-Array)). However, the latter statement doesn't make a whole lot of sense (to me at least). Accordingly, what determines the internal arrangement of the array elements?

Comment: Note (since you quoted a GNU awk reference), that in `gawk` you can control the traversal using the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored as a hash table:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Intro.html

So what this means is that awk calculates the hash of a key and puts it into a particular bin, and this is how the key value pairs are stored. You can read more about hash tables here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: :$ ... Apparently, I need to read footnotes, but thanks I'll mark this as the answer when I am able to.